# What is springProfile in logback?

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I wanted to put my log in to aws CloudWatch.
So I googled it and copied one of them.

But I understand what other thing's do but I can't under stand what springProfile does.
What is springProfile and when does it get trigger?

I'll show my code below.

```
<configuration packagingData="true">
    <timestamp key="timestamp" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ssSSS"/>
    
    <springProperty name="AWS_ACCESS_KEY" source="cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey"/>
    <springProperty name="AWS_SECRET_KEY" source="cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey"/>

    <appender name="aws_cloud_watch_log" class="ca.pjer.logback.AwsLogsAppender">
        <layout>
            <pattern>[%thread] [%date] [%level] [%file:%line] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
        <logGroupName>Kculter-log</logGroupName>
        <logStreamUuidPrefix>Kculter-log-</logStreamUuidPrefix>
        <logRegion>ap-northeast-2</logRegion>
        <maxBatchLogEvents>50</maxBatchLogEvents>
        <maxFlushTimeMillis>30000</maxFlushTimeMillis>
        <maxBlockTimeMillis>5000</maxBlockTimeMillis>
        <retentionTimeDays>2</retentionTimeDays>
        <accessKeyId>${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}</accessKeyId>
        <secretAccessKey>${AWS_SECRET_KEY}</secretAccessKey>
    </appender>

    <appender name="application_log" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%thread] [%date] [%level] [%file:%line] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <springProfile name="(local | development)">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="application_log"/>
            <appender-ref ref="aws_cloud_watch_log"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="(stage | production)">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="application_log"/>
            <appender-ref ref="aws_cloud_watch_log"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="com.example" level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="aws_cloud_watch_log"/>
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your application will be using that particular appender while logging in a particular spring profile.

example :

```
<springProfile name="(local | development)"> // only application_log appender will be use if your spring.profile=local
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="application_log"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="(stage | production)">// only aws_cloud_watch_log appender will be use if your spring.profile=stage/production & so on. 
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="aws_cloud_watch_log"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="com.example" level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="aws_cloud_watch_log"/>
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
```

hope you get the idea.